# Assigning Foreign Key through PDO SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, phpmyadmin

Currently I have to tables of concern, it is for a hotel booking site; the first table is guests and the other is bookings. These tables are linked by a constraint and the primary key is the Guest ID on the guests table and the Foreign Key is GuestIDFK2 on the bookings table.

In order to identify guests through the booking table the FOREIGN KEY needs to be put in there. The problem is I have no idea how to assign the foreign key through PDO as I don't know where to get the information from. (By that I mean sure I can assign it a value but where do I get the information from)? can I store it in a session variable or something if so how?

My connection and first query code is below. This assigns an auto increment ID but i have no idea how to copy that over to the FK when doing the second query.

```
<?php
//Connecting to db adding customer
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sgh_bookings","root","");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$resultquery1 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `guests` VALUES ('','$_SESSION[cusfname]','$_SESSION[cusaddress]','')");
$resultquery1->execute();
$resultquery2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT into ``");
}
?>
```

Comment: `session_start()` and jam it into `$_SESSION['theGuest']` ... http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php  ... make sure you clear it (`$_SESSION['theGuest']`) when you are done with that guest

Comment: But how do I put the id in there in the query?

Comment: if you are seeking to remain open to sql injection attacks, then just convert old `mysql_*` examples from the internet the way you are doing. In your case, you are not `preparing` a statement at all. You are running a query string. I recommend that you read the PDO manual pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After insert data to guests table, then pic the last inserted id and inset it to booking table 
example:

```
<?php
//Connecting to db adding customer
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sgh_bookings","root","");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$resultquery1 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `guests` VALUES ('','$_SESSION[cusfname]','$_SESSION[cusaddress]','')");
$resultquery1->execute();
$id = $conn->lastInsertId();
//insert the $id in following table
$resultquery2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT into ``");
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir! Simplistic straight forward in hindsight. Your answer has been marked correct!

Answer (score 1):

Shamelessly poached from Manual page [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). Tweak accordingly. Use a variable  like `$theGuest` or the session variable directly. Use `bindParam`, you are in `PDO` anyway, leverage it :>

**If you are using PDO, use PDO.**

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by binding PHP variables */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':colour', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->execute();
?>
```